# How can I add embed an image with links into a github readme file?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I want to add something like a class diagram, made with plantuml, to a readme.md file, but I have links in the .svg file and want the reader to be able to click them from the readme.

I managed to get it working but when you click the svg it takes you to a raw.github page with only the diagram and from there you can navigate through the links. But I want the reader to be able to navigate directly from the readme, without having to click twice on the diagram.

Also it would be interesting to know if there's a way to generete the svg directly from the plantuml code, I think there are some services that allows you to do that.

Here's an example, in the plantuml code I have something like this:

```
@startuml
abstract class Bob {
  [[http://www.example.com]]
}
Bob -> Alice : hello
@enduml
```

which creates this link: `http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/IqmgBYbAJ2vHICv9B2vMSCfFKgZcKb28ZiueAIcmqjSlBo_NIwr8p2t8ITLBpi-DZUMgvG8fqhLJSCp9J4vLi5B8ICt9oGS0`

So in the markdown I tried this: `![Alt text](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/IqmgBYbAJ2vHICv9B2vMSCfFKgZcKb28ZiueAIcmqjSlBo_NIwr8p2t8ITLBpi-DZUMgvG8fqhLJSCp9J4vLi5B8ICt9oGS0)`

When I click Bob it will take me to the example website, but as I said, first I have to click in the whole image, then on Bob.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the Markdown you have tried as well as the URL you want it to point to?

Comment: Sure @Waylan I just added some sample code, let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did some testing and the problem is that links embedded in SVGs only work when the SVG is included with an `<object>` tag, but not with an `<img>` tag. Consider the following example HTML:

```
<h3>A PNG Image with embedded link:</h3>

<img alt="PNG" src="http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/IqmgBYbAJ2vHICv9B2vMSCfFKgZcKb28ZiueAIcmqjSlBo_NIwr8p2t8ITLBpi-DZUMgvG8fqhLJSCp9J4vLi5B8ICt9oGS0" />

<h3>A SVG Image with embedded link:</h3>

<img alt="SVG" src="http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/svg/IqmgBYbAJ2vHICv9B2vMSCfFKgZcKb28ZiueAIcmqjSlBo_NIwr8p2t8ITLBpi-DZUMgvG8fqhLJSCp9J4vLi5B8ICt9oGS0" />

<h3>PNG as Object:</h3>

<object data="http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/IqmgBYbAJ2vHICv9B2vMSCfFKgZcKb28ZiueAIcmqjSlBo_NIwr8p2t8ITLBpi-DZUMgvG8fqhLJSCp9J4vLi5B8ICt9oGS0" type="image/svg+xml"></object>  

<h3>SVG as Object:</h3>

<object data="http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/svg/IqmgBYbAJ2vHICv9B2vMSCfFKgZcKb28ZiueAIcmqjSlBo_NIwr8p2t8ITLBpi-DZUMgvG8fqhLJSCp9J4vLi5B8ICt9oGS0" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

If you save the above as a local HTML file and load it in your browser you will see that only the last one works.

So the answer is to use Raw HTML to include an `<object>` tag which points to the SVG file. Of course, much of the raw HTML is stripped by GitHub, so it may not work in a README. But it would work on GitHub Pages.

---

You state that the image is a SVG, however the URL includes "png". I would be surprised if embedded links worked in a PNG file. Make sure you really are using a SVG file.

In fact, I just visited your image link (http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/IqmgBYbAJ2vHICv9B2vMSCfFKgZcKb28ZiueAIcmqjSlBo_NIwr8p2t8ITLBpi-DZUMgvG8fqhLJSCp9J4vLi5B8ICt9oGS0) and I got back these response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Expires: Sat, 24 Feb 2018 16:44:02 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 22 Dec 2009 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public
Content-Type: image/png
Connection: close
Server: PlantUML/0.6
```

Note specifically `Content-Type:image/png`. You probably want `image/svg+xml`. And in fact, Bob is **not** clickable.

However, if I change "png" in the URL to "svg" like this: http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/svg/IqmgBYbAJ2vHICv9B2vMSCfFKgZcKb28ZiueAIcmqjSlBo_NIwr8p2t8ITLBpi-DZUMgvG8fqhLJSCp9J4vLi5B8ICt9oGS0 then I get a svg file in which Bob **is** clickable. And, in fact, I get these repsonse headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Expires: Sat, 24 Feb 2018 16:37:34 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 22 Dec 2009 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public
Content-Type: image/svg+xml
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding, User-Agent
Connection: close
Server: PlantUML/0.6
```

Unfortunately, when editing the sample on the homepage of http://plantuml.com I couldn't get that to work. It was only when going to their separate [editor page](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/) that I succeeded. I'm not sure if that is because the homepage only gives you a PNG or because of the reason discussed below...

If, on the other hand, you really are using a SVG file, then it would seem that something is causing your image to be wrapped in a link. Turning that off may resolve your problem.

Let's look at http://plantuml.com for an example.

On their home page they have a diagram which is clickable (the entire image, not just a portion of it). If we "view source", we see that the image tag is in fact wrapped in an anchor tag:

```
<a href=http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml><img id="im" src=http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/SyfFKj2rKt3CoKnELR1Io4ZDoSa70000></a>
```

We see the image:

```
<img id="im" src=http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/SyfFKj2rKt3CoKnELR1Io4ZDoSa70000>
```

is wrapped inside the link:

```
<a href=http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml>...</a>`
```

However, on [other](http://plantuml.com/sequence-diagram) [pages](http://plantuml.com/sequence-diagram), the images are not wrapped in links and therefore they are not clickable. If you can get your entire image to not be clickable, then perhaps a link inside the image would be recognized and be clickable.

Unfortunately, that may not be possible. You mention that you are including the image in your README and you mention GitHub. I'm assuming that your README is being hosted on GitHub. GitHub includes a (helpful) script on their site which finds all images and wraps them in a link which points at the image. Of course, GitHub does not provide a way for users to disable that script. You seem to be in one of the rare situations were the script is actually not so helpful. For the kind of control you desire, you would need to host your own documents on your own server where you have full control.

Comment: No the PNG does not work. You do **not** get clickable links embedded in the image. I've edited my answer to better reflect that.

Comment: I don't have any preference between PNG or SVG, or any other format, I just want to be able to show a class diagram where clicking in the entities takes you to the explanation of the entity. But you say that's not possible in github readme files, right? If so, looks like I should put it in github pages and amend the HTML since I'm generating it from Markdown as well.

Comment: Yes, you understand. Although you should prefer SVG as the embedded link will never work with PNG. But, yes, using GitHub pages should resolve the issue of GitHub blocking the embedded link.

Comment: But do you think it's a limitation of github readme? Or is it a limitation of the markdown renderer in general?

Comment: I expect that the images are being wrapped by a JavaScript script in the browser, which you would have complete control over in GH Pages. Besides, GH Pages uses a different Markdown render anyway.

Comment: I just updated my answer again. This time I have a real (tested) solution. I left the old stuff in there as it is still somewhat relevant, but the answer is in the new first section.

Comment: Thanks. I tried also with object but the problem was that it seems to be disabled in github readme. I hope it's only a github readme limitation and not a general limitation of the markdown.

Comment: Yes, GitHub strips out raw HTML as a security measure. In general, Markdown allows any raw HTML through.

Comment: Thanks again. I can confirm what you say since I already went that path and everything seems to be working fine.